# Scrapy outputting the same thing hundreds of times

Tags: python, scrapy

I followed the tutorial on the scrapy page, and I tried to just edit the code to practice on wikipedia. When I do, it outputs the text in the page, but it does so hundreds of times. The JSON file as well as the console contains the same thing printed over and over. I think it may be something to do with the function? Also, what is the difference between sel.xpath and site.xpath?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(Spider):
   name = "dmoz"
   allowed_domains = ["wikipedia.com"]
   start_urls = [
       "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_Hull"
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       sel = Selector(response)
       sites = sel.xpath('//div')
       items =[]
       for site in sites:
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('.//p/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
       return items
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want second xpath to be relative to first one, instead of:

```
item['title'] = sel.xpath('.//p/text()').extract()
```

do:

```
item['title'] = site.xpath('.//p/text()').extract()
```

looping on `//div` create as many divs as they found in the document of course.

running `sel.xpath('.//p/text()')` is the same as running `sel.xpath('//p/text()')` hence keep getting the same result over and over again

Comment: I see, thank you, do you see why the code would be printing the same thing many times?

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, but I'm not sure. I'm sorry I'm new to this. I changed //div to .//p, but it still gives me the repeated results. Can you point to which part of the code needs to be changed?

Comment: pls try to give an example of what's been repeated

Comment: When I output it to a txt file in JSON, I now get all of the same text printed 25 or 30 times in the document.

Comment: I think I possibl see whats happening but I'm not sure, the loop is repeating all the previous entries everytime it adds a new one, so by the end the entire thing is repeated many times. Do you know how to fix this so that each item is only printed once?

Comment: If anyone has any thoughts on this, it would be greatly appreciated! I have tried everything I can think of.

Comment: the problem is that it isnt clear from your question what is repeating

Comment: Okay, so when the code above is run, the output from the scraper, i.e. all of the text on the website, repeats in the output over and over. It repeats in the console, and when I output it to a txt file, I open it and have a file that contains all of the text on that page printed many many times. What is in the code that is causing it to scrape and print the same thing over and over (which is all the text on the page)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but did that make the question more clear?

Comment: Im still really not sure what is the outcome you expect to get but for example this won't repeat `[text for text in sel.xpath('//div/p//text()').extract()]`